# DNS technique for the path part of the domain

Tags: dns, cpanel

probably there' re many answer for my problem on google, but i don' t really know how to search for.

Is there any DNS "technique" which will result a different IP for:

```
http://example.com/apple
```

and for

```
http://example.com/frog
```

? If yes, what is it? I' d appreciate some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

DNS only operates on the domain and subdomain(s).

If you want to have different IPs for the different URLs, you can setup a proxy which will send the different requests to the different IPs.

Suppose example.com resolves to `192.0.2.1`. All requests to `example.com` will come to `192.0.2.1`.

Now, if you have a proxy, you can specify to redirect `example.com/apple` to `192.0.2.2`, `example.com/frog` to `192.0.2.3` and so on...

Here is a link for how to do this in nginx

> https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

If your really want `example.com/apple` to resolve to different IP than `example.com/frog`, you might want to consider using this as a subdomain.

So, instead of using `example.com/apple`, you could setup separate DNS entries for `apple.example.com` and `frog.example.com`

This way they can resolve to different IPs.

Comment: Please do not use frivolous IP addresses as example and **ESPECIALLY** not `1.1.1.1` that  exists and is used worldwide now (CloudFlare public DNS resolver). I will rewrite your post using RFC5737 IP addresses.

Comment: I do know that 1.1.1.1 is a CloudFlare public DNS. However, the OP's question is about how they can set up/configure their own DNS entries, not to be confused with the DNS at 1.1.1.1. So, IMO, it does not matter if we use 1.1.1.1 as an example, or RFC5737 IPs, or any other IPs for that matter. Its only a coincidence that 1.1.1.1 is a DNS, and the question is also about DNS albeit about completely different topics.

Comment: You are wrong. It does matter. For example the TLD `.mail` can no exist today because so many people used it previously in documentation and examples that it is burnt and never useable. CloudFlare has many problems because a lot of people hijacked this IP and used it in their configuration. It is WRONG to use it as an example. And trying to hide this fact behind a pure coincidence on topic is very misleading. Why not just accept there are specific IP for examples for a good reason and be a good netizen?